# audiocalls.wav could not be decoded

Tags: html, html5-audio, wav, playback

I am trying to play a wav file using html 5 audio player but it shows file could not be decoded.
Anyone please let me know what is wrong with this wav file so it is unable to play in html5 audio player.
I am working on a call recording system that records these kind of wav files and now I am integrating html 5 audio player to play in system.
If file does not support in html 5 audio player then please let me know any alternative option to play file in system.
Below is url to download wav file
http://sipprintdemo.com/callrecording3/download.php?file=../../../sipprintcalls/2016/05/17/15/20160517_152047_XRT.wav

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say why it is not decoding without seeing your code. What browser are you using in order to test? .wav files do work with HTML audio but not all browsers support that file type. I know that IE for example does not support it.

Another option would be to convert the files to .mp3 format that is support by all browsers. A quick google search should yield a converter service for you.

Comment: Tried using Jpalyer It didnt work. Requirement is to play wav files with bit rate 13. From what i have read browsers only support 8 and 16 Kbps files. But the files i need to be played are in 13Kbps.